# How to render list in elm?

Tags: list, render, elm

I have a hard time to render List of custom types within the view function.
This is the model:

```
type alias Guid = String
type alias User = String

type alias TaxonomyCategory =
  { id : Guid
  , name: String
  , updatedAt: Date
  , updatedBy: User
  , terms: List TaxonomyTerm
  }

type TaxonomyTerm =
  TaxonomyTerm
    { id : Guid
    , name: String
    , terms: List TaxonomyTerm
    }
```

I tried several approaches with List.map function but I always ended up with some kind of error message.

```
The 2nd argument to function `ul` is causing a mismatch.

120|       ul
121|         []
122|>        [ List.map renderTaxonomyTerm tc.terms ]

Function `ul` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    List (VirtualDom.Node a)

But it is:

    List (List (Html a))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter of `ul` should be a list of Html elements. Your second value contains a list within a list since you surrounded it with brackets. Changing it to this should fix your problem:

```elm
ul
  []
  (List.map renderTaxonomyTerm tc.terms)
```

Comment: I'm betting you probably want to define TaxonomyTerm as a type alias instead of a new type, e.g. `type alias TaxonomyTerm = { id : Guid, ... }`

Comment: But then I would get an error about recursive type in TaxonomyTerm

Comment: You can instead change your `renderTaxonomyTerm` function to something like this: `renderTaxonomyTerm (TaxonomyTerm t) = text t.name` which pattern matches against the single `TaxonomyTerm` constructor and uses the label `t` as the record value, allowing you to use `t.name` to access the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

For using `ul` see previous answer. Thanks to Chad.

I have an addition. You can't create recursive records. You should create structure like `type TaxonomyTerm = TaxonomyTerm Guid String (List TaxonomyTerm)`.